# Change list elements index with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, indexing

I hava a list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item_1">element</li>
    <li class="item_2">element</li>
    <li class="item_3">element</li>
</ul>
```

After some drag and drop action i'm switching elements positions, so after this my list looks like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="item_2">element</li>
    <li class="item_3">element</li>
    <li class="item_1">element</li>
</ul>
```

I need to replace classes of this elements after this dragging action to get sorted list again - state before dragging.

So, i'm doing this:

```
var setItemNumber = function(item) {
    item.each(function(i) {
        $(this).removeAttr('class').attr('class', 'item_' + (i + 1));
    });
}
```

What is happening is that elements are changing classes but their are in the same positions, it looks like they doesn't change index and this iteration is acting on previous DOM list state.

How can i change this, or maybe something else? Can anyone help?

Comment: Provide more context in question. Show how do you drag/drop elements. A jsFiddle would help i guess

Comment: Why do you need to identify the order via the use of classes? Can you not use the `index()` of the elements?

Comment: What exactly you want? you want to move the Element up??

Comment: Elements are moving, with this everything is fine, i need to add new ordered classes for elements of this list

Comment: @Lukas But how do you call `setItemNumber()` function? On drop event? You have to provide it in question itself and a minimalistic sample to replicate issue

Comment: yes, i'm calling it on/after drop event, i need to catch dragged element class and after couple of seconds set up a new classes for whole list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are you looking for is this:

```
reindexItems = function() {
     var items = $('ul li');
     var i = 1;
     items.each(function() {
         $(this).removeAttr('class').attr('class', 'item_' + i++);
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to rename the classes then you can do for example

```
var elements = $("li");
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    $(elements[i]).attr("class", "item_" + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to reorder elements in DOM changing class names wont work. You have to actually sort them and since you are using Jquery

```
    var setItemNumber = function(item) {
        $(item).sort(function(a,b){
        var an = a.attr('class').replace("item_","")
        bn = b.attr('class').replace("item_","");
        if(an > bn) {
             return 1;
        }
        if(an < bn) {
             return -1;
        }
        return 0;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some solution also:

```
var setItemIndex = function(item) {
    // iterate each marked item
    item.each(function() {
        // get index of item
        var i = $(this).index();
        // set new index based on item class
        $(this)
            .removeAttr('class')
            .attr('class', 'item_' + (i));
    });
};
```